# UIScrollView Help

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uitabbar

Is there a way to put several UIViews In a UIScrollView in a tabbar page. If so, how would I do that? To make it simple, Imageine the homescreen icons on the springboard. Each page is a UIView. I want to basically put this on a tabbar page. Is this possible? How would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE:
First try to accept the answers then only you will get lot of good answer from our seniors.....

first create the uiscrollview and then add that it to the tabbar... for creating the uiscrollview

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];  
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;  
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;  
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {  
CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;  
UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,   self.view.frame.size.height)];  
awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];  
[scroll addSubview:awesomeView];  
[awesomeView release];   
}     
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```